# how do you convert to datetime in R

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to convert this t field to datetime in R. This is the vector:

```
dput(t)
"01-DEC-15 04.50.14.000000000 PM"
```

I tried this:

```
tt<-as.POSIXct(t, format="%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%S %p")
```

when I print out the tt, I get NA. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
R> strptime("01-DEC-15 04.50.14.000000000 PM", 
+           "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.000000000 %p")
[1] "2015-12-01 16:50:14 CST"
R>
```

You were using the wrong qualifier for the year, and I am not sure that the am/pm toggle would have gotten that way.